# Wordpress Slider with source images from PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I need an image slider for Wordpress in which the images com from PHP. Something behaving like:

```
[slider]
<?php
get_slider_images();
?>
[/slider]
```

with `get_slider_images()` echoing lines like:

```
<img src="xxxxx.jpg" title="dummy title">
```

Does any one know any suitable plugin (or any other solution)?
Note: I have done my search, but couldn't find anything.

Thanks!!

Comment: Where will your images come from? Will the slider shortcode accept parameters?  Do you want to add this to a theme, or create a plugin?

Comment: I need a slider that accepts dynamic content, generated by PHP. I retrieve the images from a table of walking tours, and I want to show the next 5 upcoming walks in the slider. So the content for the slider will be different every day.

Comment: So - what have you tried so far? What do you have as far as php code to retreive your images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flexslider option:

```
$parts = enter in your image urls;

$description .= '<div class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">';

    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        $description .= '<li><img height="200" width="342" src=' . $part . "> </li>";
    }

    $description .= "</ul></div>";
```

jsfiles
http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/